# jQuery .text() method repeating itself. How to make it run only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<tr class="<%= payment_paid(f.paid)%>" id="paidrow">
     <td>
       <% if !f.paid %>
       <%= check_box_tag "pin_number[]", f.id, checked= !f.paid? %>
       <%end%>
     </td>

     <td class="pin"><%= f.year %></td>
     <td class="val"><%= f.quarter %></td>
     <td align="right" class="price"><%= number_to_currency(f.amount, unit: "", precision: 2)%></td>


      <script>
        mergecommonrows();
        setTimeout(addpaidrows,1000);
      </script>
  </tr>

function addpaidrows(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $("#property_dtl_table_body");
    var rows = table.find("tr#paidrow.payment_paid");
    var first = parseFloat(rows.find('.price').text());
    sum = first;
    var startIndex = 0;
    var lastIndex = 0;
    var startText = rows.find('.price').text();

    var colsLength = 4;
    var removeLater = new Array();

    for(var i=3; i<colsLength; i++){
      for(var j=1; j<rows.length; j++){
        var cRow =$(rows[j]);
        var cCol = $(cRow.find('.price'));
        var currentText = cCol.text();
        var currentNumber = parseFloat(cRow.find('.price').text());
        cCol.css("background","#c8fcc1");
        console.log(cCol);
        removeLater.push(cCol);
        lastIndex=j;
        var spanLength = lastIndex-startIndex;
        if(spanLength>=1){
          console.log(lastIndex+" - "+startIndex)
          //console.log($($(rows[startIndex]).find('.price')))
          $($(rows[startIndex]).find('.price')[i]).attr("rowspan",spanLength+1);
        }
        lastIndex = j;
        startIndex = j;
        startText = currentText;

      var spanLength = lastIndex-startIndex;
        if(spanLength>=1){
            console.log(lastIndex+" - "+startIndex)
            //console.log($($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]))
            $($(rows[startIndex]).find('.price')[i]).attr("rowspan",spanLength+1);
        }
      console.log("---"); 
     sum = sum + currentNumber; 

      }
    }


    console.log(sum);
    var frist = rows.find('.price').text();




    for(var i in removeLater){
          $(removeLater[i]).remove();
      }    

      $('tr#paidrow.payment_paid td.price').text(sum.toFixed(2))    
});
}
```

I'm making a program where after the Javascript file does its thing, the text in the upper right hand corner of the table will be replaced with the 'sum.toFixed(2)' variable (in this case, 67.97). It works, but the problem is that the .text() method repeats itself, causing the result to become NaN, since the other numbers required to make the sum.toFixed(2) are erased after it has been added to the sum. And based on the console below, it seems that that is the cause of the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can not take document.ready inside a function!!

Comment: *"...but the problem is that the .text() method repeats itself..."* No, it doesn't. Letting go of the idea something magically repeats itself will let you move forward to finding the real cause of the problem.

Comment: @SmitRaval: Sure you can. It's rarely useful (but is sometimes, depending on when the function is called).

Comment: Can you please explain how? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @SmitRaval: Suppose I have a library with an `init` function consumers of the library are supposed to call. I have no control over when they call it, and they may well call it from script executed immediately from a `script` tag in the `head` -- e.g., long before any `body` elements exist. So to defend myself from that kind of (mis)use, I use `$(document).ready(...)` in `init`.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for your explanation @T.J.Crowder :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `text` is slightly unusual as compared to other jQuery methods. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

Almost every other accessor function in jQuery accesses only the **first** of the matched elements, but `text` combines all of their text.

If you want the text of only the **first** matched item, you have to do that on purpose:

```
var first = parseFloat(rows.find('.price').first().text());
// ---------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but unless I can actually get the code to change the text of the first matched item, I'm still stuck to where I am now.

Comment: @thepersonwho: It's the same : `rows.find('.price').first().text("new text here")`. (Of course, you might want to store and reuse the result of `rows.find('.price').first()`.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I added an if-else statement that checks if the sum is NaN (not a number) or not. If it is NaN, no output will be shown. But if it isn't, the output will show.

```
      if (sum != sum){

      }
      else {
         rows.find('.price').first().text(sum.toFixed(2));
      }
```